# How to group two appended dataframes by a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have 2 dataframes with the same column names, for example:

```
col1 col2 col3
1    2    3
```

and

```
col1 col2 col3
4    5    6
1    7    8
```

I have appended them, so now the new dataframe is like below:

```
col1 col2 col3
1    2    3
4    5    6
1    7    8
```

The problem is that I need the rows that have the same value in the col1 to come one after the other, just like this:

```
col1 col2 col3
1    2    3
1    7    8
4    5    6
```

How can I sort the dataframe by col1 to create this effect(without modifying the dataframe type)?

Comment: then sort them i.e `df=df.sort_values('col1')`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_values('col1', ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you care about ensuring that dataframe 1 values are sorted before dataframe 2 values where they are tied, you can use the 'mergesort' algorithm. The default algorithm will arbritarily order any tied values.

```
df.sort_values(by='col1', axis=1, ascending=True, inplace=True, kind='mergesort')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort a DataFrame by any column, for example:

```
df.sort_values(by=['col_1', 'col_2'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)
```

After that you may like to reset the row index, as they will be jumbled up:

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```